# Linux SD (mmc) read/write: where is it actually done?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, sd-card

In order to support data mangling I need to write a custom device driver inserting a short amount of code at latest possible moment before actual write to SD (mmc driver) and, specularly, at the earliest possible moment after data is read back from SD.

I am aware all I/O is done using DMA transfer directly from/to disk cache structures, this means I will have to allocate a new buffer, transcode buffer to temp, point DMA to temp and start transfer. Reverse path on read.

Ideally I should use standard kernel crypto facilities (dm-crypt and LUKS), but my linux device is a small embedded ARM device which slows to a crawl with standard encryption, so I'm willing to trade some security for speed and settle for a "smart-obfuscation" instead of true crypto.

I need to find the point where to insert my code. In that point I need to have access to the data buffer, the sector number where buffer will be written/read and be able to redirect DMA transfer to a temp buffer.

kernel/drivers/mmc/core/core.c seems to have only routines dealing with card as a whole (reser, reset, ...) and not for actual data handling.

I have been unable to find the right place (to date) can someone point me to the right file, please?

EDIT:
As pointed out in a comment I don't really need to change data at the "absolute last moment", but that seemed the best solution because:

- Mangling will no change data length.
- Mangling depends on actual logical sector.
- Data in disk cache should remain readable and usable.
- Only data going to SD needs to be mangled (no mangling for data in Flash).
- I will need to do the same modification to a desktop PC to be able to read/write SDs used in the embedded system.
- Overhead should be kept as low as possible (embedded has low mem and computational power).

Any (roughly) equivalent solution can be evaluated.

I am also willing to forgo DMA usage and force PIO-mode for SD if that makes things easier; this would lift requirement of sector copying as requested mangling can be done "on the fly" while transferring data from buffer to peripheral.

Comment: Your requirements are suspect.  Why do you think this has to be done at the last possible point?  Do you realize that this point is in a specific device driver (without specifying that driver)?   The MMC can be accessed by streaming or block operations, but when mounted as a filesystem, the MMC is a block device (i.e. you have to read/write in units of a sector).  So you realize that you cannot change the length of the data?

Comment: @sawdust: You are right, I might do that in some other place, but I didn't find a better one. I will update OP to reflect the fact. My mangling won't change data size. I want to mangle only data belonging to a specific device.